# remembering form field value on django model form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am quite new to Django as such, and have been playing around with ModelForms. So far, I have been able to create ModelForms with ease. However, one problem seems to bug me a bit:

When a user fills the form, and if there is an error (say `int` instead of `char` or a missing `blank=False` value), the form spits out the error and seems to *forget* the values the user entered when the form failed to validate. I am wondering if there is a way to *remember* these values so that the user does not have to enter them again.

At the moment, I have something like the following:

```
class ContactForm(CreateView):

    form_class = ContactForm
    template_name = "superform.html"
    success_url = '/ty/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # do something useful with validated form
        return super(ContactForm, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        # do something useful with invalidated form.
        return super(ContactForm,self).form_invalid(form)
```

I am assuming I need to do something in `form_invalid` to pass the values back to the form - but I am unsure how to do this(?).

I would really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

--*--Edit---*

```
            <form class="form" role="form" action="{% url 'coolurl' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

                    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
                      <div class="alert">
                      {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                      <span class="label">Error: {{ error|escape }}</span> 
                      {% endfor %}
                      </div>
                    {% endif %}


                    <div class="form-group">
                        {% if form.name.errors %}
                          <div class="alert">
                          {% for error in form.name.errors %}
                          <span class="label">Error: {{ error|escape }}</span> 
                          {% endfor %}
                          </div>
                        {% endif %}

                        <label class="col-sm-3" for="id_name">Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input class="form-control" 
                             id="id_name" 
                             type="text" 
                             name="name" 
                             maxlength="128" 
                             placeholder="Your name..">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: No, this should be the default behaviour. Please can you show your form template?

Comment: sounds like a problem with your template. definitely nothing to do with ajax

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Anentropic: thanks for the comment. What you have said makes sense, since, when I use `{{form_as.p}}` everything is fine and it seems to remember the values the user has enetered even when there's an error. I have now shown my template (with just one field since the form markup is quite big). Wondering what I am doing which is different to `{{form_as.p}}`.

Comment: just an FYI: I am using twitter bootstrap to generate the form markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to mention the value of the `input` tag:

```
<input class="form-control" 
                             id="id_name" 
                             type="text" 
                             name="name" 
                             maxlength="128"
                             value="{{ form.name.value|default_if_none:'' }}"
                             placeholder="Your name..">
                        </div>
```

Comment: you rock! :) your answer does the trick for all `input` tags!  except for `textarea` - `value` does not seem to work under this. Any thoughts? :(

Comment: OK I got it. Just used `{{...}}` straight on textarea's value. Thanks again - you saved me a bunch of time. Accepted your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You've taken the responsibility for rendering those fields away from Django by simply hard-coding them in the HTML. That means that Django has no way of inserting the current values; not only when redisplaying after errors, but also if you have a form that modifies existing database content.

Don't do it like that. I understand that you don't want to just juse `form.as_p`, but there is a good middle ground: output each field in the template with `{{ form.my_field }}`. You can add relevant classes to the fields in the definition in forms.py, and then Django will take care of outputting it correctly.

Comment: I agree with your comment. In this case, the answer from `arocks` works!